# most efficient way to update a property of a property in a Javascript object for React hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, optimization, react-hooks

I have the following object in the `useState`:

```
const [obj, setObj] = React.useState({ 
       one: {
          index: "one",
          name: "Number one"
       },
       two: {
          index: "two",
          name: "Number two"
       }
    });
```

What I want is to update `index` or `name` in a single call. I have this:

```
function update(from, what, value) {
   const objTemp = {...obj};
   obj[from][what] = value;
   setObj(objTemp);
}
```

I call this function like: `update('one', 'index', 'Hey')` or `update('two', 'name', 'Foo')`. I have been trying and I can handle this scenario:

```
const [x, setX] = React.useState({ one: 'One', two: 'Two' });

function updt(from, value) {
   setX({...x, [from]: value});
}
```

But I was unable to find a way to optimize my first function like the last one. I tried:

```
setObj({...obj, [from][what]: value});
```

But it certainly didn't work. Is there any way to optimize my `update` function to look like my `updt` function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close, essentially you need a second object spread/mutate of the nested object you're updating.

```
setObj({...obj, [from]: { ...obj[from], [what]: value} });
```

**Note:** You are still shallowly copying an entire object, i.e. each innumerable property, so this is *technically* as efficient (in terms of Big-O) as what you already have/had. (*Maybe even a bit less so as there are now **two** spread operations!!*)

One could also argue it is now a bit less readable as well, now reduced to a one-liner.

The important step for react state updates is the pure function paradigm of always returning **new** object references, which is the reason for the initial object spread.

I should also note that it isn't recommended to store complex objects in `useState` hooks *for this very reason*, maintaining correct state update with deeply nested updates is a lot more work. `useReducer` is then generally recommended for these situations. The same update complexity exists, but it's a clearer pattern.

```js
const obj = {
  one: {
    index: "one",
    name: "Number one"
  },
  two: {
    index: "two",
    name: "Number two"
  }
};

function update(from, what, value) {
  return {...obj, [from]: { ...obj[from], [what]: value} };
}

console.log(update('one', 'name', 'Number 1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

with complex state like that you should not useState, just try useReducer

```
const initialState = { 
       one: {
          index: "one",
          name: "Number one"
       },
       two: {
          index: "two",
          name: "Number two"
       }
    };

function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'update':
      const { property, subProperty, value } = actions.payload
      const newState = {
        ...state,
        [property]: {
          ...state[property],
          [subProperty]: value
        }
      }
      return newState;
    default:
      throw new Error();
  }
}
```

then you can use it with

```
dispatch({type: 'update', payload: {"one", "name", "Number 1"})
```